# Why random numbers aren't appeared in array?

Tags: for-loop

Hi im new at Java so probably im going to ask a stupid question and I want to know why the random numbers are not appeared in System.out.print()?

```
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
         int randomNum=(int)(Math.random()*100)+1;
         int [] secretNum=new int[randomNum];
      System.out.print(secretNum[i]+" "); 
    }
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
```

Comment: you are not storing any value in array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you generate a random number `r`, you create an empty array of length `r` (which by default it's filled with zeroes only), instead of storing the generated value on the `i`-th position of `array`.

You should rather do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
     array[i] = randomNum;
     System.out.print(array[i]+" "); 
}
```